# get() in CustomerRepository doesn't receive $customer from retrieveByEmail() for password reset

Tags: magento2, customer, password-recovery, get

I've got the weirdest problem I've ever come across, I'm not brilliant with class based systems so maybe its not magento related...

So the basics are that the reset password function isn't working. I've narrowed it down to **$customer** not being received from a function that is definitely returning it.

```
resetPassword() in \vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\AccountManagement.php
```

gets the **$customer** from

```
get() in \vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository.php
```

which gets the **$customer** from **retrieveByEmail()** in

```
\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\CustomerRegistry.php
```

so **retrieveByEmail()** definitely gets the customer, but **get()** doesn't ever receive it.

I've tested it by swapping **retrieveByEmail()** to just **retrieve()** with a single customerID and it works ( up to the next problem which is save($customer) but thats for another day.

I just can't figure out why **retrieveByEmail()** returns a **$customer** object but **get()** doesn't receive it?

any ideas?

***edit***
thanks @Kristoffer, I have checked the storeID is the correct store and retrieveByEmail is sending back the same customerID 67 that I tested with retrieve(67).

I can't see how or why get() isn't receiving the customer that retrieveByEmail is sending, but it is receiving that from retrieve()

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the customer you are trying to load by email is not a customer at the website your are running as.

If you check the code for retrieveByEmail it has:

\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry::retrieveByEmail

```
if ($websiteId === null) {
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
                ?: $this->storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getWebsiteId();
}
```

Just as a test here you can change this code and set $websiteId = the website id you know that the customer is a customer of and see if it loads correct.

In Magento admin a customer can be set either to global scope or website scope. If set to website scope a single email can have different customer ids in Magento for every website.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

there was a custom plugin intercepting the process but not returning the result